# Horizontal vs Vertical SQL with Custom Column Headers

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm struggling finding the most efficient way to approach this DB design.  This is for a Client who want to manage their Contacts.  The Software currently is Horizontal which allows each Client to modify up to 5 columns for Field label questions.  These 5 static columns are also in the Contact's table to store the results per Contact.  For this example we are only using two tables, Client and Contact.

The Issue.  I have been asked to extend this so a Clients can have an N amount of custom Field Label questions. One Client my want 1, another may want 20, 34, or N.  I can't see this being done correctly Horizontally but easily vertically.  The issue then becomes, I have to make a pivot to display the Vertical results in a row/column display.

The Question.  Am I looking at this wrong, and should I change my perspective, and stick with a Horizontal table?  If so, could someone explain to me the approach I should take?

Comment: What is the app written in? Do you have control over that application and is changing the way it renders your data in scope?

Comment: @maplemale It's a LAMP stack, and all tings considering I have control of the scope.

Comment: You should add the PHP tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider storing the data in XML in a 3rd table with a FK relationship to the Client table. Your xml would have additional elements for each N number of custom fields. Then change the application so instead of displaying static fields, it derives those fields from the XML.

The plausibility of my answer depends somewhat on the architecture of the application displaying this data and assumes you have control over changing it. Since the question is a bit vague, and I don't even know what language your app is written in or whether it is web based or not, I can't really provide you with any code examples.

Comment: How would this affect Filters and searches?

Comment: Do you want to provide search options on any custom field? There are only 3 ways I can see my proposal working very well:

1. If you have a limited number of contacts (say a few hundred at most) and are applying the filters after the data is returned from the database, programatically.

2. Not allowing our customers to filter on the custom fields, but providing some static fields that each contact record must have which can be filtered on and only allowing filtering on those fields.

3. A combination of 1 and 2.


If this doesn't seem feasible, see Sander's answer above. That may work better.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the orientation of the columns; have PHP handle the presentation.

Store each of the custom column names in a table `Columns` with columns `ColumnID`, `ClientID`, `ColumnName`, and `SortOrder`. Create a second table `ColumnValues` with columns `ColumnID`, `ClientID`, `ContactID`, and `Value`, and store the values that correspond to each of the custom column names for every one of each client's contacts.

Have your application code build an HTML/CSS table with the following logic:

1. For the first row, list each of the `ColumnName`s for the `ClientID` you're working with, in the same order as the `SortOrder` values for each of your `ColumName`s
2. Create individual rows below this first row for each of your `Contacts` for this `ClientID`. On each row, list the `ColumnValue`s for each of the for the `Contact` that corresponds to the row you're building, in the same `SortOrder`, for this `ClientID`.

Comment: This was basically my plan, my question is more based on performance, and future issues where N is involved.

Comment: What I'm saying is get rid of the pivot, and have PHP do the work of pivoting the data as you'd like. SQL is very good at set-based operations like this, while PHP is good at performing tasks sequentially, like populating cells in a table one by one. As long as you have good indexes on all your tables, this database structure should be a piece of cake to handle for any somewhat modern device. This method is scalable up until perhaps several thousands, or tens of thousands, of columns.

Comment: Do you have any links to examples, to make sure I'm not thinking of something different?